# Creating DLL from a Fortran subroutine to be used in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, dll, fortran

My goal is to find a way to call Fortran subroutine in Excel VBA (can be found on [Prof Alan Genz](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/homepage). The program is MVNPACK) to compute the CDF of multivariate normal distribution. Ideally, I would like to be able to use a version of DLL compiled from that source code in a C# project as well in the future. However, I am not sure how to troubleshoot and proceed further. I typically code in Python, have some exposure in C, Java, etc., but never use Fortran and not too familiar with what's going on when one calls a function in a DLL. To the best of my knowledge, this computation is not that widely available, and compiling the Fortran source code is my best bet.

I have been closely following the example [here](https://simplyfortran.com/blog/4/) about creating the DLL, and [here](https://simplyfortran.com/blog/5/) about using that in Excel VBA, and been trying to mimic the result. Starting from the MVNPACK source code mentioned above, I figured that what I need is to pass the inputs to the subroutine MVNDST, and get the result back by passing the pointers as arguments to the subroutine. So the first thing I did was trying to modify the code based on what the examples did. My modified version MVNDSTC looks like this.

```
    SUBROUTINE MVNDSTC( N, LOWERC, UPPERC, INFINC, CORRELC, MAXPTS,
     &                    ABSEPS, RELEPS, ERRORC, VALUEC, INFORMC)
     & bind(c)
      use ISO_C_BINDING
      implicit none
cGCC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL, DLLEXPORT :: MVNDSTC
      EXTERNAL MVNDFN
      
      integer(kind=c_long), value:: N, MAXPTS
      real(kind=c_double), value:: ABSEPS, RELEPS
      
      type(c_ptr), value:: LOWERC, UPPERC, INFINC, CORRELC
      type(c_ptr), value:: ERRORC, VALUEC, INFORMC
      
      real(kind=c_double), dimension(:), pointer:: LOWER, UPPER, CORREL
      integer(kind=c_long), dimension(:), pointer:: INFIN
      real(kind=c_double), dimension(:), pointer:: ERROR_OUT, VALUE_OUT
      integer(kind=c_int), dimension(:), pointer:: INFORM_OUT
      
      INTEGER NN
      INTEGER INFORM, INFIS, IVLS
      DOUBLE PRECISION ERROR, VALUE, E, D, MVNDNT, MVNDFN
      COMMON /DKBLCK/IVLS
      
      NN = (N - 1) * N / 2
      call C_F_POINTER(LOWERC, LOWER, [N])
      call C_F_POINTER(UPPERC, UPPER, [N])
      call C_F_POINTER(INFINC, INFIN, [N])
      call C_F_POINTER(CORRELC, CORREL, [NN])
      call C_F_POINTER(ERRORC, ERROR_OUT, [1])
      call C_F_POINTER(VALUEC, VALUE_OUT, [1])
      call C_F_POINTER(INFORMC, INFORM_OUT, [1])
      
      IF ( N .GT. 500 .OR. N .LT. 1 ) THEN
         INFORM = 2
         VALUE = 0
         ERROR = 1
      ELSE
         INFORM = MVNDNT(N, CORREL, LOWER, UPPER, INFIN, INFIS, D, E)
         IF ( N-INFIS .EQ. 0 ) THEN
            VALUE = 1
            ERROR = 0
         ELSE IF ( N-INFIS .EQ. 1 ) THEN
            VALUE = E - D
            ERROR = 2D-16
         ELSE
*
*        Call the lattice rule integration subroutine
*
            IVLS = 0
            CALL DKBVRC( N-INFIS-1, IVLS, MAXPTS, MVNDFN, 
     &                   ABSEPS, RELEPS, ERROR, VALUE, INFORM )
         ENDIF
      ENDIF
      VALUE_OUT(0) = VALUE
      ERROR_OUT(0) = ERROR
      INFORM_OUT(0) = INFORM
      END
```

Then I created a small subroutine with the mvndstc declaration on top. The VBA code is as follows.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub mvndstc Lib "C:\Users\poopa\Desktop\mvn\mvn_project\fortran-library.dll" _
    (ByVal N As Integer, _
     ByRef LOWER As Single, _
     ByRef UPPER As Single, _
     ByRef INFIN As Single, _
     ByRef CORREL As Single, _
     ByVal MAXPTS As Integer, _
     ByVal ABSEPS As Double, _
     ByVal RELEPS As Double, _
     ByRef ERROR As Single, _
     ByRef VALUE As Single, _
     ByRef INFORM As Single)

Sub mvn_test()
    Dim value_1(1 To 1) As Single  ' Result of the function
    Dim inform_1(1 To 1) As Single  ' Information
    Dim error_1(1 To 1) As Single  ' Error estimate
    Dim upper_1() As Single
    Dim lower_1() As Single
    Dim infin_1() As Single
    Dim correl_1() As Single
    Dim n_1 As Long, n_1_2 As Long, max_pts_1 As Long

    n_1 = 5
    ReDim lower_1(1 To n_1)
    ReDim upper_1(1 To n_1)
    ReDim infin_1(1 To n_1)
    lower_1(1) = 0#
    lower_1(2) = 0#
    lower_1(3) = 1.7817
    lower_1(4) = 0.14755
    lower_1(5) = 0#
    
    upper_1(1) = 0#
    upper_1(2) = 1.5198
    upper_1(3) = 0#
    upper_1(4) = 0#
    upper_1(5) = 1.5949
    
    infin_1(1) = 1
    infin_1(2) = 2
    infin_1(3) = 1
    infin_1(4) = 1
    infin_1(5) = 0

    n_1_2 = Int(n_1 / 2 * (n_1 - 1))
    ReDim correl_1(1 To n_1_2)
    correl_1(1) = -0.707107  ' 12
    correl_1(2) = 0#  ' 13
    correl_1(3) = 0.5 ' 14
    correl_1(4) = 0#  ' 15
    correl_1(5) = 0.5 ' 23
    correl_1(6) = 0.5 ' 24
    correl_1(7) = 0#  ' 25
    correl_1(8) = 0.5 ' 34
    correl_1(9) = 0.5 ' 35
    correl_1(10) = 0.5 ' 45
    
    max_pts_1 = 625000
    mvndstc n_1, lower_1(1), upper_1(1), infin_1(1), correl_1(1), max_pts_1, 0.00005, 0, error_1(1), value_1(1), inform_1(1)
    Debug.Print "Value = " & (value_1(1))
    Debug.Print "Error Est = " & (error_1(1))
    Debug.Print "Inform = " & inform_1(1)
End Sub
```

Now my first attempt I did not modify ERROR, VALUE, INFORM parameters at all and simply declare then in Fortran as theirs respective primitive types. I can actually run the VBA subroutine, but I got all zeros for the results. So I was speculating that the program runs but perhaps I didn't get the result back properly and I should treat these three outputs as pointers with size of 1. That way I just keep whatever procedure exactly the same in Fortran and then if I put VALUE_OUT(0) = VALUE and so on, before the function ends I should be get the results just fine. Right now using the code I posted here, I can actually see the results printed out in VBA, still all zeros, but right after that Excel would immediately crash.

So I want to ask how do I proceed from here? What did I got wrong here? Is there any resource worth looking into?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would be better off rewriting that FORTRAN code in C#. Then you can make a COM visible DLL that works in both Excel and in C# programs. The links you shared didn't mention anything about how to make the FORTRAN DLL **COM visible** or using `Regsvr32.exe` to register the DLL.

Comment: Try starting with a simple example - add 2 numbers and return the result.  When you get that working, and fully understand it, try passing an array and summing up the elements and returning the result.  Just do it in simple steps - don't jump in at the deep end and expect to swim immediately.

Comment: Make sure your data types agree.  I see `Single` on the VBA side that appears to be lining up with a double-precision `REAL` on the Fortran side; that's a recipe for trouble (likely to lead to crashes).  Similarly, VBA `Integer` is only 4 bytes, so a `c_long` may not agree; those should probably be `Long` on the VBA side.

Comment: @Craig Thank you Craig. I fixed this yesterday, the problem is indeed about the data types. When I read the tutorial I was assuming Single is some kind of object type in VBA. Little did I know that Single is actually the single precision of Double! I tried debugging all this by letting the DLL print out all the values inside the function to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this yesterday, the problem is indeed about the data types. When I read the tutorial I was assuming Single is some kind of object type in VBA. Little did I know that Single is actually the single precision of Double! I tried debugging all this by letting the DLL print out all the values inside the function to a file.